# Changing address of a struct in C++ by ++ and -- operator

Tags: c++, struct, operator-keyword

Is it possible to change the address of my current struct using the -- or ++ operator, i.e.:

```
mystruct* test = existing_mystruct;
test++ // instead of using: test = test->next_p;
```

I was trying to use this, but it seems to be const and gives me an Error: assignment to this (anachronism):

```
struct mystruct {
    mystruct* next_p;
    mystruct* prev_p;

    void operatorplusplus  () { this = next_p; }
    void operatorminusminus() { this = prev_p; }
};
```

Comment: `this = (anything)` is highly unlikely to work in a standard compiler.  IIRC `this` is considered const.

Comment: @cHao: IIRC `this` is an rvalue expression, which is even less assignable than `const`.

Comment: Historical note: `this` used to be modifiable, way back in the early days; assigning to `this` in the constructor was the analog of today's placement new.

Comment: @PeteBecker so you'd just lose the memory you used to occupy?

Comment: @SethCarnegie - I've already told you everything I know about this. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker what is <g>? It is not googlable.

Comment: @SethCarnegie - kids these days. :-( "<g>" is "grin". Now, please don't ask what :-( is. <g>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects have a constant address in memory while they exist.
You may copy them to a new address, however.

What you try to do is advance in a linked list. And it may be done with those operators if you overload them. But you will need to define that in a special handle class to wrap over the list nodes.

**EDIT**

The code for what I describe will look somewhat like this:

```
class mylist
{
  struct mynode
  {
    //data
    mynode* next;
    mynode* prev;
  } *curr;

public:
 mylist& operator++() {curr = curr->next; return *this;}
};
```

Naturally you'd wanna do boundry checks and such, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So it is possible to overload these operators for a pointer to this struct?

Comment: It's possible to overload them for any class/struct.
But if you want to advance in a list you need a wrpper.
Give me a sec to edit my answer.

Comment: @DimaRudnik Maybe a better name for the wrapper is `mylist_iterator`

Comment: @anatolyg, perhaps.
But since the classic doubly linked list api of `next`,`get` and `prev` can be replaced with the appropriate operators, a list is kinda it's own operator.

Comment: @DimaRudnik: In implementing the `++` operator, it is customary to returning a reference to self.

Comment: @MatthieuM.
Indeed, I overlooked it. Now it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

No. `this` pointer is of type `mystruct * const`, which means its address is unchangeable.